# FileProvider : Install apk programatically - Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: android, android-install-apk, android-fileprovider

I am using FileProvider  to install apk from my app. Followed many stackoverflow questions but still facing this issue

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tssi.myapptour/files/download/myapp_newSigned.apk
```

My provider in manifest

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.tssi.myapptour.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

my file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="download" path="download/" />

   <!-- <external-path name="download" path="Android/data/com.tssi.myapptour/files/download/" />-->

</paths>
```

And my code for calling apk

```
String strApkToInstall = "myapp_newSigned.apk";
File fileApkToInstall = new File(getExternalFilesDir("download"), strApkToInstall);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
        fileApkToInstall);
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in `getExternalFilesDir()`. That does not match `files-path` in your `FileProvider` metadata. Either:

- Switch to `getFilesDir()` (a much better solution from a security standpoint), or
- Switch to `external-files-path`

See [the `FileProvider` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#SpecifyFiles) for more about the mapping between filesystem locations and metadata entries.

Comment: Make it path="."